# Minesweeper - end of game

Tags: actionscript-3

My minesweeper game doesn't stop when you win. I need help with the code that will stop the game and display "You Win".

Everything works well and "You Lose" - works too.

```
package {

// importing classes
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
// end of importing classes 
public class Main extends Sprite {
    // class level variables
    private const FIELD_W:uint=9;
    private const FIELD_H:uint=9;
    private const MINES:uint=5;
    private const fill_tile=1;
    private const empty_tile=2;
    private const mine=3;
    private const flag=4;
    private var emptyTile:tile_movieclip;
    private const qty=FIELD_W*FIELD_H;
    private var mineField:Array=new Array  ;
    private var game_container:Sprite=new Sprite  ;
    private var tile:tile_movieclip;
    private var timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
    private var toolbar:toolbar_mc;
    private var gameOver:Boolean=false;
    private var firstClick:Boolean=true;
    // end of class level variables
    public function Main() {
        // mine field creation
        for (var i:uint=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) {
            mineField[i]=new Array  ;
            for (var j:uint=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) {
                mineField[i].push(0);
            }
        }
        // end of mine field creation
        // tile creation
        addChild(game_container);
        for (i=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) {
                tile=new tile_movieclip  ;
                game_container.addChild(tile);
                tile.gotoAndStop(fill_tile);
                tile.nrow=i;
                tile.ncol=j;
                tile.buttonMode=true;
                tile.x=5+(tile.width+0.5)*j;
                tile.y=5+(tile.height+0.5)*i;
                tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            }
        }
        // end of tile creation
        // time management and game over
        toolbar=new toolbar_mc  ;
        addChild(toolbar);
        toolbar.y=stage.stageHeight-toolbar.height;
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
        // end of time management and game over
    }
    private function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void {
        toolbar.message_text.text="Elapsed time: "+e.target.currentCount+"s";
    }
    private function onTileClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (! gameOver) {
            var clicked_tile:tile_movieclip=e.currentTarget as tile_movieclip;
            var clickedRow:uint=clicked_tile.nrow;
            var clickedCol:uint=clicked_tile.ncol;
            if (firstClick) {
                firstClick=false;
                // placing mines
                var placedMines:uint=0;
                var randomRow,randomCol:uint;
                while (placedMines<MINES) {
                    randomRow=Math.floor(Math.random()*FIELD_H);
                    randomCol=Math.floor(Math.random()*FIELD_W);
                    if (mineField[randomRow][randomCol]==0) {
                        if (randomRow!=clickedRow||randomCol!=clickedCol) {
                            mineField[randomRow][randomCol]=9;
                            placedMines++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // end of placing mines
                // placing digits
                for (var i:uint=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) {
                    for (var j:uint=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) {
                        if (mineField[i][j]==9) {
                            for (var ii:int=-1; ii<=1; ii++) {
                                for (var jj:int=-1; jj<=1; jj++) {
                                    if (ii!=0||jj!=0) {
                                        if (tileValue(i+ii,j+jj)!=9&&tileValue(i+ii,j+jj)!=-1) {
                                            mineField[i+ii][j+jj]++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var debugString:String;
                trace("My complete and formatted mine field: ");
                for (i=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) {
                    debugString="";
                    for (j=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) {
                        debugString+=mineField[i][j]+" ";
                    }
                    trace(debugString);
                }
                // end of placing digits
            }
            var clickedValue:uint=mineField[clickedRow][clickedCol];
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(5-clicked_tile.currentFrame);
            } else {
                if (clicked_tile.currentFrame==fill_tile) {
                    clicked_tile.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
                    clicked_tile.buttonMode=false;
                    // emptyTile tile
                    if (clickedValue==0) {
                        floodFill(clickedRow,clickedCol);
                    }
                    // end of emptyTile tile
                    // numbered tile
                    if (clickedValue>0&&clickedValue<9) {
                        clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(empty_tile);
                        clicked_tile.tile_text.text=clickedValue.toString();
                    }
                    // end of numbered tile
                    // mine
                    if (clickedValue==9) {
                        clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(mine);
                        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
                        toolbar.message_text.text="You LOSE!!!";
                        gameOver=true;
                    }

                    // end of mine
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function tileValue(row,col:uint):int {
        if (mineField[row]==undefined||mineField[row][col]==undefined) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return mineField[row][col];
        }
    }
    private function floodFill(row,col:uint):void {
        emptyTile=game_container.getChildAt(row*FIELD_W+col) as tile_movieclip;
        if (emptyTile.currentFrame==fill_tile) {
            emptyTile.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            emptyTile.buttonMode=false;
            emptyTile.gotoAndStop(empty_tile);
            if (mineField[row][col]>0) {
                emptyTile.tile_text.text=mineField[row][col].toString();
            } else {
                emptyTile.tile_text.text="";
            }

            if (mineField[row][col]==0) {
                for (var ii:int=-1; ii<=1; ii++) {
                    for (var jj:int=-1; jj<=1; jj++) {
                        if (ii!=0||jj!=0) {
                            if (tileValue(row+ii,col+jj)!=9) {
                                if (tileValue(row+ii,col+jj)!=-1) {
                                    floodFill(row+ii,col+jj);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow!](stackoverflow.com/faq) Although we're happy to help with your programming problems here, we do this in our own free time - so we can't be expected to do your work for you... Try to reword your question in a way that it's easier for us to troubleshoot. What part of your code is failing? What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead? What else have you tried?

Comment: i will try to help you but it takes some time.(:

Comment: I tried - if (clickedValue==qty-MINES) { timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
                        toolbar.message_text.text="You WIN!!!";
                        gameOver=true; } But it doesn't work. I can't to do code\function or condition than count free tiles and after display "You Win"

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a new flag (something like 'minesLeft=1') and then when the Mines count is 0, set that to 'minesLeft=0'. This would let you display a game over message and maybe a 'restart' or 'quit' option.

I'd say its worth a shot. 
Cheers.